# Get dimension of element on another site using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of urls which all have an div in them with an id of 'section_container'.
On a completely seperate url I would like to access this page, detect the width of the container and return that value back, hopefully all through a post call or something.

Can this be done? I own all the domains by the way.

Comment: by access this page does it mean that you have iframe from your current site page to that of the one containing `#section_container`

Comment: Yes I guess so... I hadn't really thought that the site would have to render in order to detect the size of anything. Hmmmm.

Comment: Is the width dynamic? If not, you could pull the CSS file and interrogate that.

Comment: @optimusprime619 - No... but that's not a bad idea. I could render it in an iframe and detect it by accessing in from there?

Comment: @StuperUser - yes it's dynamic I'm afraid.

Comment: @HelenDangerBurns the iframe trick wont work if its a different domain, due to security sandboxing.

Comment: You could use the plugin suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213049/get-dimension-of-element-on-another-site-using-jquery/10213122#10213122 on an iframe

Comment: @j08691 - the ids are unique. each is on a different site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make jQuery work across domains which can be done by using this plugin: [Cross Domain Plugin](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/).

You can then use $.ajax get to fetch the page and locate that div, once you have this div you can get the width and height of it.

Comment: No problem hope it helps! You can also use it on iframes

Answer (score 3):

Due to security features such as the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), I do not think you would be able to do this (mostly because of [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)).

However, if you own all of the domains, you may be able to set up some sort of API across your sites to get the height of that element.  This would need to be done on the server, obviously, but then any of your sites would be able to grab that info as needed.